# Unable to create interactivity with programs that make stdin requests

Tags: c, linux

In C (with linux), I am trying to mimic the functionality of the bash shell but it is unable to handle programs that require user input. Taking a simple adding program as an example:

```
Please enter 1st digit
>

Please enter 2nd digit
>

Answer is:
```

Can someone suggest with maybe a basic example code how to (respectively):

```
1. run the test program
2. store the test program output
3. recognise that there is a stdin request
4. enter sample digits into the test program.
```

It doesn't need to have interactivity with the user at this point, just allow interactivity between other programs and itself.

The main problem is that I can't find any examples or even clear routes to research on how this can be done. Bash can do it, but how!

Comment: StackOverflow is not the proper place for this question. We do not write your code for you. You need to do your own coding and if you aren't sure why something is not working as expected, post the code with an explanation of what you were expecting it to do, and what it is actually doing including all error messages. See [about StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/about).

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Can you clarify with an example? Show or describe the steps that your program takes in a typical use case.

Comment: There is a place for a everything. The code asked was not worth fretting about. I am sure the person is able to do it in the other language and just tries to replicate the functionality in the language they learn now.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you were looking for?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int i;
    printf("Enter something:");
    scanf("%d",&i);
    printf("You entered %d\n", i);
}
```

Comment: Please, 3 months is more than enough time to le- okay never mind

Comment: @ashcliffe: You format code by adding 4 spaces before each line in the code. Or use the button with the `{}` above the text box when you go edit it.

Comment: @ashcliffe: No, there's a button with `{}` in it in the toolbar above the text box where your answer is.